# Optimization for weighted quadratic cost function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratics

The cost function is

$f=\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_i(A_ix-b_i)(C_ix-d_i)$

Where $A_i$ and $C_i$ are 1 by $L$ vectors, $b_i$, $d_i$ and $w_i$ are known constants, and $x$ is a $L$ by 1 vector with all elements positive.

How to calculate the $x$ that can minimize the cost function.

I would be very appreciated if someone could help.

Comment: This is almost certainly not convex. It would be if $A_i=C_i$, but the fact that you're deliberately saying they are different quantities suggests otherwise.

Comment: I was trying to figure out if it's convex, but I couldn't make it referring to the definition of convex optimization $f(ax+by)<=af(x)+bf(y)$. Could you tell why it's not convex when $A_i$ is different from $C_i$?

Comment: Consider the $L=2$ case, with $A_ix=x_1$ and $C_ix=x_2$. So that product becomes $x_1x_2$, which is easy to verify is not convex.

Comment: I see. Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Quadratic Programming (QP) solver, of which there are many for almost any computing environment.. That will allow you to specify the nonnegativity constraint.If you need $x$ to be strictly positive, you will have to specify small_number and input constraint as $x \ge $ small_number.

All QP solvers can handle this problem if the objective function is convex, and will find the global minimum. If the objective function is not convex, you will need a QP solver which can handle non-convex QPs.  Non-convex QP solvers come in two type, 1) Find local but not necessarily global minimum 2) find global minimum . For non-convex QPs, you can also use a general purpose non-convex nonlinear solver (which can handle linear constraints) instead of a dedicated QP solver.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I am trying to use simulated annealing to find the global minimum, but it takes more time than the convex optimization algorithms.